# nginx http authentication with python

Tags: python, apache, authentication, nginx

I'm migrating from Apache2 to NGinX and I want to authenticate via a python script. The Apache2's working configuration is:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /hg $SCRIPT_DIR/hgwebdir.wsgi
WSGIPythonPath $SCRIPT_DIR
<Location /hg>
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Mercurial"
    AuthBasicProvider wsgi
    WSGIAuthUserScript $SCRIPT_DIR/authentication.py
    Require valid-user
</Location>
```

What would be the equivalent configuration in nginx?

Comment: Just for the records: you need the nginx [auth_request module](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_request_module.html) to do this kind of thing. It’s very easy to use. The only thing you need in your application is an endpoint that either returns 2xx or 401/403.